# Saving KPIs at end of simulation run

Tags: output, anylogic

Have been trying for a long time to search back and forth to find a solution to this, but nothing found that fits my situation.

Until now, I have manually (!!!) written down numerical output from the simulation into documents. This is very tedious as you can imagine, there are 29 KPIs of interest and most are fractional numbers with +3 digits.

Basically, I want to save values at the end of the simulation runs. Once the model has stopped, I want the text either exported to an excel file or at least output in such a way that I can curate the data further.

An example of how the first value is calculated here (under Time to treatment - Tot.) is:

v_N == 0 ? null : roundToDecimal((v_Total_Time_To_Treatment / (v_N*3600.0)), 3)

[image: Picture of the values]

Update:
Based on feedback, I decided to make a 'simple' solution based on print line to console like such:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the settings of the `simulation` experiment there is an event called After the simulation run (You will find more details [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/simulation-experiment.html#simulation-experiment)), you can access your metrics for example: `root.MyKPI`.

Using the Excel File object will help you save your metrics to Excel

Comment: Just to highlight this answer: Go learn about the experiment properties as Yossi suggests. You are making your life infinitely harder than it ever needs to be :)